# Binary search tree traversal method, in order toString

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, tostring

I made a binary search tree from scratch with my own nodes which functions perfectly when I add nodes and when I print the tree in order to the console. However, I'm having a time and a half getting the `toString` method working.

I changed my `toString` method to `MakeString`, because I thought it was getting confused when converting comparable type data to a string. I can either get the method to return one node or just in object form, but never the whole tree in string form. The `printInOrder()` method works perfectly, so why won't my `MakeString()` method?

```
public void printInOrder(){

    if (left != null) left.printInOrder();

     System.out.println(data);

    if (right != null) right.printInOrder();
}

public String MakeString(){

    String OrderedTree;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (data == null) return "Tree is empty";

    if (left != null) left.MakeString();

     sb.append(data);

    if (right != null) right.MakeString();
```

Comment: Please paste the whole class. Also, you're not using the result of `left.MakeString()`.

Comment: Also please show us what text output you really want here.  Printing out a binary tree to the console is a readable way seems like a challenge to me regardless of the code.

Comment: the last line is missing, but it's just return sb.toString();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need something to be preserved throughout the recursion, then it should be passed as a parameter. This will often result in a pair of methods if you want  to avoid having to prep the initial call or otherwise have something to do before or after the recursion.

In your case you are using a `StringBuilder` which needs to be created before the recursion, preserved throughout, and then used afterward.

Ex:

```
public String MakeString() {
   if (data == null)
      return "Tree is empty";

   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

   MakeString(sb);

   return sb.toString();
}

private void MakeString(StringBuilder sb) {
   if (left != null)
      left.MakeString(sb);

   sb.append(data);

   if (right != null)
      right.MakeString(sb);
}
```

Comment: That works so much smoother! In the state of mind I was in this morning, I was having it print to a file and then reading it out of the file. Two methods! Perfect, thank you!